# Show Google V3 recapatcha just on one page, hidden on others

Tags: css, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I've seen solutions to this for Wordpress/Contact 7 but not for websites that have been developed in Dreamweaver etc – I've hidden the recaptacha V3 icon on a website I'm putting together, using the following CSS coding:

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

But would like it to appear just on the contact form page, is this possible?

Comment: What about changing the visibility of the badge depending on the window route?

Comment: what would be the most efficient way of doing that?